# Solving a recurrence with division

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations, recursion

I'm having this recurrence that is giving me a lot of trouble.

$$F(2^0) = 1$$

$$F(2^k) = \frac 1 2 F(2^{k-1}) + 2^k$$

I will edit my post since this does not seems to work...

The initial recurrence is :

$$F(1) = n$$
$$F(n) = \frac 12 F(\lfloor\frac n 2\rfloor) + n$$

So I tried to resolve it for $$n = 2^k$$

So i have :

$$ 1/2^{k-i} * F(2^{k-i}) + \sum\limits_{j=k-i+1}^{k} 2^j  $$

With k=i, at final I get 2n-1... Where did I messed up ?

Comment: Why do you think that something here is wrong?

Comment: because this gives me 2n-1...

Comment: It was giving you exactly what DanielV wrote. I hope you understand his solution, but if you don't, feel free to write what seems to be the problem. I don't know if you can comment his answer; if not, comment here.

Comment: His/my solution gives me $$ 1/2^{k-i} * F(2^{k-i}) + \sum\limits_{j= k-i+1}^{k} 2^j  $$ which can't be right since the answer to that is : 2n-1. Answer should be (my intuition) something like 1/n + ...

Comment: Before you edited, your question had this: $\frac 1 {2^3} F(2^{k-3}) + \frac n {2^2} + \frac n {2^1} + n$. This is what Daniel wrote. So, take his solution and use [this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometric_series#Geometric_series) for $a=n$ and $r=1/2$.

Comment: How do you write the sum of $$ \frac{2^{k-3}}{2^3}  +  \frac{2^{k-2}}{2^2}  +  \frac{2^{k-1}}{2^1}  +  2^k $$ for J values ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11024/discussion-between-tuqwpora32-and-vedran-sego)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be on the right track.  Just keep going until you see a pattern.

$\begin{align}
F(2^k) &= n + \frac 1 2 F(2^{k-1}) \\
       &= n + \frac 1 2 (n + \frac 1 2 F(2^{k-2})) && =  n + \frac n 2 + \frac 1 {2^2} F(2^{k - 2}) \\
       &= n + \frac n 2 + \frac 1 {2^2} (n + \frac 1 2 F(2^{k - 3})) && = n + \frac n 2 + \frac n {2^2} + \frac n {2^3}F(2^{k - 3}) \\
       & \dots \\
       &= n + \frac n 2 + \frac n {2^2} + \frac n {2^3} + \frac n {2^4} + \dots  + \frac n {2^j}F(2^{k - j})
\end{align} $

Eventually $k=j$ and so the last $F(2^{k - j}) = 1$.  Got a little geometric sum there.

Comment: How would you write the sum of $$ \frac{2^{k-3}}{2^3} + \frac{2^{k-2}}{2^2} + \frac{2^{k-1}}{2^1} + 2^k $$ for J values ?

Comment: For $j$ values I would write it as $$\sum_{p = 0}^{j - 1} \frac {2^{k - p}} {2^p}$$ but if you are doing that then I think you are on the wrong track.  The numerate should be a constant $n$, not $2^{k - p}$

Comment: ugh I am not sure I follow. What do you mean?